# Vue сумма значений в объекте

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
[
  {
    "date": "18.01.2021",
    "retail": "212747",
    "ur": "66847",
    "yandex": "243400",
    "bn": "88766",
    "return": "11747"
  },
  {
    "date": "17.01.2021",
    "retail": "186360",
    "ur": "4540",
    "yandex": "234577",
    "bn": "122395",
    "return": 0
  },
  {
    "date": "16.01.2021",
    "retail": "145334",
    "ur": "3712",
    "yandex": "257950",
    "bn": "69175",
    "return": "13165"
  }
]
```

Как посчитать значение в объекте суммы retail, ur, yandex и bn от 18.01.2021?

Answer (score 1):

#### [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

> Метод reduce() применяет функцию reducer к каждому элементу массива
> (слева-направо), возвращая одно результирующее значение.

```js
const data = [
  {
    "date": "18.01.2021", "retail": "212747", "ur": "66847", "yandex": "243400", "bn": "88766", "return": "11747"
  },
  {
    "date": "17.01.2021", "retail": "186360", "ur": "4540", "yandex": "234577", "bn": "122395", "return": 0
  },
  {
    "date": "16.01.2021", "retail": "145334", "ur": "3712", "yandex": "257950", "bn": "69175", "return": "13165"
  },
  {
    "date": "18.01.2021", "retail": "145334", "ur": "3712", "yandex": "257950", "bn": "69175", "return": "13165"
  }
];

const {retail, ur, yandex, bn} = data.reduce((acc, item) => {

  if (item.date === '18.01.2021') {
    ['retail', 'ur', 'yandex', 'bn'].forEach((key) => {
      if (key in item) {
        acc[key] = (acc[key] || 0) + (+(item[key] || 0));
      }
    });
  }
  return acc;

}, {});

console.log(retail, ur, yandex, bn)
```

Comment: хороший пример. Только reduce кажется избыточным. Можно же просто `acc += item[key]` .